# Popup not getting the full navbar size

Tags: css, navbar, semantic-ui

I'm facing a problem here,

The popup element `LINES` is getting the size of `<div class="right menu">` instead of the `<div class="ui top attached menu">`. Because of that, my popup is the same size of the right menu, I need the popup to be the same size of the entire navbar

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qawdfw0y/1/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Will the entire navbar always be 100% of the screen width?

Comment: Yes, the navbar will have a fixed width (actual screen resolution)

Comment: It's worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: No problem. Glad it's doing what you want it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is exactly what you're going for... but it looks pretty good to me:

```
.ui.popup {
  min-width: 98vw;
  left: 1vw !important;
}

/* To move the arrow on the box */
.ui.bottom.center.popup:before {
  right: 320px;
  left: auto;
}
```

I know the use of `!important` isn't typically the best, but the `style` is getting set by semantic.js. The only alternative would be manipulating semantic.js in order for this to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your popup element is inside the .right class element, so it will definitely take it's width.

What you can try is

> .right{ width: 100%;}

and also to in your popup block.

```
<div class="ui fluid popup bottom left transition hidden" 
style="top: 554px; left: 1px; bottom: auto; right: auto; width: 100%;">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I lost some elements with this

Comment: You can try removing your popup element out of the right div then!